# Java Files "File cannot be accessed because it is being used by another program"

Tags: java, swing, file-io

I balieve this is a common error around here, but mist of the thread I  find are either for C# or not useful for my problem.

I'm trying to eliminate a line from a text file and to do so I'm creating a temporary text file and copying everything except that line there. After close the reading and writing streams, I get an error saying I can't name (copy) the file because it is being used by another program. I thought the problem could be the closing of the streamings, but it is done before trying to copy the file, so have do idea what the problem is. So far, my code is like this:

```
 private void removeMailBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws IOException{
    String origPath     = "emails/"+radioSelected(buttons).toLowerCase()+".txt";
    String cpyPath      = "emails/new"+radioSelected(buttons).toLowerCase()+".txt";
    Path originalPath   = Paths.get(origPath);
    Path copyPath       = Paths.get(cpyPath);
    String carrier      = null;

    BufferedReader copier = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(originalPath.toString()), "ISO-8859-1"));
    BufferedWriter paster = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(copyPath.toString()));

    String compare = comboBoxMails.getSelectedItem().toString();


    while((carrier = copier.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(!carrier.equals(compare))
        {
            paster.write(carrier);
            paster.newLine();
        }
    }

    copier.close();
    paster.close();

    //Files.delete(originalPath);
    Files.move(copyPath, originalPath, REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Files.delete(originalPath);
    test.sucessHandler();
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that this method *consistently* fails with the error you reference, regardless of choice of input file?

Comment: And you're saying that there's no way that any other program could have the target file open?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Already tried to restart the PC and run tis right away and stull does not work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger also tried it with diferent files and got the same result